# Android: Using a string in place of an object/instance name

Tags: android, string

I would like to see if I can avoid a lengthy switch or if block by directly converting some strings into an object name.  For example, I have a class called Example and I want to [edit] have up to 10 instances of the class Example1, Example2, so on.  Can I use something like:

```
  int ExampleNum = 2;    
// can be changed to any 1-10 value corresponding to instances
    String s = "Example" + String.valueOf(ExampleNum);

Refresh(s);

public void Refresh(Example example){
...
}
```

Thus I would create a string with the value of Example2 and pass that to my Refresh method.

[edit]
I don't want to use all the instances at once, but rather have other methods that change the int ExampleNum so that when I try to refresh it refreshes the appropriate Example instance.

Rather than saying:

```
if (ExampleNum == 2)
    Refresh(Example2);
```

I would use the ExampleNum and String to use the right instance name;

Comment: why don't put them in an ArrayList, and just pass the position to your Refresh method ?

Comment: You're passing a `String` to a method which takes an `Example`...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  How would I get the method Refresh(Example example) to use the instance of class Example called Example2 somehow using the String s.  Is there a way other than creating an arrary of Example class instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use array's instead??

```
Example[] e = null;
    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {
        e[i] = new Example();
        Refresh(e[i]);
    }
```

Comment: So that is an array of Examples? such that e[1] would give me Example1?

Comment: Yes!.e[1] will be your first instance, e[2] second and so on...instead of Example1, Example2...

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code, as it stands now, doesn't make any sense since you're passing a `String` to `Refresh`, which takes an `Example` object as an argument.

However, if you're asking how you can create the strings Example1, Example2, ... Example 10, you can do this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    s = "Example" + i;
    refresh(s); // assuming this takes a string
}
```